# X11.app disappeared when upgrading 10.15 to 10.15.1?

Tags: catalina, x11

Yesterday I upgraded from 10.15 to 10.15.1. Today when I tried to launch an X-window application  I realised that X11.app had disappeared. Does anyone recognize this? Why did it happen?

Comment: How did you install it, where was it installed into? And did you run a find across the whole disk to see whether it got moved somewhere else by the upgrade?

Comment: X11 has stayed on my Mac through several installs of Catalina betas. I have it installed in /Applications/Utilities. If it's somewhere else, it might have been removed, disabled or discarded.

Comment: What version was your Xcode.app? Catalina needs vers. 11.x, so you need to reinstall it if it was not at least 11.

Comment: @nohillside I installed it from XQuartz.org a Oct 7.

Comment: @Yoan It was updated (due to MacPorts) after I installed Catalina but I hadn't updated it to the version released a few weeks ago until the other day, when this happened.